# How can i convert for loop to AngularJs forEach?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to JavaScript world just want to clarify this because i am using AngularJs client side.Below code is working as expected but question is,Is there a way to achieve below result with Angular loop `forEach` ?

ctrl.js

```
for (var i = 0; i < selectedOwners.length; i++) {
    if (selectedOwners[i].workerKey === obj.workerKey) {
        selectedOwners.splice(i, 1);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try JavaScript's `.filter()`

Comment: just so you know, that for loop is more performant.  also, theres a native js forEach that probably is as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
angular.forEach(selectedOwners, function(owner, $index) {
    if (owner.workerKey === obj.workerKey) {
        selectedOwners.splice($index, 1);
        break;
    }
});
```

Comment: `break` will not work as you are expecting inside `forEach`. Use return instead.

Comment: Perfect thanks alot i have same result with angularJs.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to filter an array is to use the native javascript .filter() function.

```
var filteredOwners = selectedOwners.filter(function(owner) { 
    return owner.workerKey !== obj.workerKey; 
});
```

Comment: its not working what we doing with filteredOwners once we return ?

Comment: filteredOwners is an array containing a subset of your original selectedOwners array items that fulfill the return condition. What is not working? Is filteredOwners empty?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this without using `angular.forEach`

```
var workerIndex = selectedOwners.map(function(owner) { return owner.workerKey; })
      .indexOf(obj.workerKey);

selectedOwners.splice(workerIndex, 1);
```